# Echo number of comments on an article and add a edit / delete button to each comment?

Tags: php

the things is quite simple i guess for some of you, but for me it is quite hard since i`m a beginner. :) i'm developing a website template on localhost and i want to integrate a blog page on it. i succesfully added the form and linked it to the database for the comments to show on the desired article page. i now need to add a delete and edit button for each comment that can be accessed only by the user who posted it and the admin, and a link that shows how many comments are in the article. Can someone give me at least a hint ?:)

Ty in advance!

this is the code i have so far...apparently i cannot post images here.

http://postimg.org/image/g3u6vrxm3/

Comment: what is your code till now?

Comment: This might be your best chance to achieve that https://wordpress.com

Comment: You might want to add some code showing what you have tried and what the results were. That is the proper way to ask for and consequently get help on SO

Comment: sorry guys, i`m new to this forum and i`m trying to understand why it doesn`t get my code indent as it should...it doesn`t display all i want so i made a picture with the code and i provided the link to it. ty all for your promptitude.

Comment: Since you are a beginner... **pause right where you are in learning PHP...** stop trying to learn `mysql`. `mysql` has been deprecated since version 5.5 and was totally removed in version 7. Soon your code will stop functioning completely. You should be learning `pdo_mysql` instead. [read about it here](php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php)

Comment: ok. will do as u advised :)

Answer (score 0):

Actually you are correct about one thing... it is quite simple.

You will first need to check each comment to find out who the owner of that comment is. Then compare the two bits of information in an "IF" statement.

IF they match OR the user is an "Admin" THEN... show the edit link.

Somewhere inside your code block for the comment put something like this...

```
<div id="mycommentblock"><?php echo $rows['comment'] ?>
<?php // sql query to find out who the owner of this comment is
// like "SELECT * FROM commenttable WHERE id=$rows['id']"
if((isset($_SESSION['userid']) && $_SESSION['userid'] == '$row_commentOwner['id']') || $_SESSION['usergroup'] == 'Admin') { ?>&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="editcomment.php?id=<?php echo $rows['id'] ?>">edit</a>&nbsp;<a href="deletecomment.php?id=<?php echo $rows['id'] ?>">delete</a><?php } ?>
</div>
```

Comment: thank you for the answer. i succesfully managed it somehow...apparently it works now and it shows me the number of comments inside the article page as i add or delete comments.

Comment: Do you need more help? If this answer was helpful to you and/or answered your question, please don't forget to [accept that answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).
Also see [What does it mean when an answer is "accepted"?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) and [Why is voting important?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/help/why-vote).

Comment: no, thank you...a friend from work helped me and i didnt tried the code above. it was a code of two lines for the comments to count themselves on the article page. if it helps other users i can post it here. ty for all your help.

Comment: You're welcome... the code for the edit and delete buttons you asked about is in my answer... good luck